# Accessing localstack images at localhost for Django ImageField

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, localstack, django-storage

I have a django rest app that I am running locally with docker and a docker-compose file.

I have a model with an image field. However, the image field has a URL in the form of `http://localstack/...` but the image is not accessible there. It is actually accessible at `http://localhost/...`.

The following is a snippet of the important bits of my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/commas-api
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "/app/start-server-local.sh"
    environment:
      STAGE: 'local'
      DB_NAME: 'api_db'
      DB_USERNAME: 'user'
      DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      DB_HOST: 'db'
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL: 'admin@example.com'
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: 'xxxx'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'dummy'
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'dummy'
      AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL: 'http://localstack:4566'
      AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'dummy'
      AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'dummy'
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      localstack:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - localstack

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - ./localstack:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d

volumes:
  commas-api:
```

The Django Rest project is using `S3Boto3Storage` where you can see the endpoint provided in the environment variables is: `http://localstack:4566`

However, if I try to change this to `http://localhost:4566`, then I get connection errors:

`botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/myBucket/static/admin/css/login.css"`

I assume this may be a networking issue between localhost and the two apps where boto is running in the app so the localhost there is different. However, I am not super experienced with docker.

My goal is to have the `image` field of my model be an endpoint that is accessible on the app/browser when I navigate to it so that my frontend running locally can load the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "the current container"; why do you want to set the S3 endpoint to point at `localhost` specifically?  It seems like `localstack` (the Compose service name of the LocalStack container) works; why change?

Comment: The main reason is when I am on my browser or loading from my react app, the image does not exist at the `http://localstack` endpoint but instead exists at the `http://localhost` endpoint.

For example, if my model has an image URL of `http://localstack:4566/myBucket/media/images/campaigns/2/imageName.jpg` I can't open it on my browser but instead if I open `http://localhost:4566/myBucket/media/images/campaigns/2/imageName.jpg` I see the image

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but can you try using `localhost.localstack.cloud` which is the recommended endpoint - especially for S3, in order to enable host-based bucket endpoints.

Comment: For network troubleshooting there is a comprehensive documentation here — https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/network-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to work with `localhost.localstack.cloud` now and still working through it.

I don't want to delete this post because of comments but will reference I new ticket where I attempted to be more descriptive of the issue I am facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106594/localstack-and-django-storages-use-custom-url-with-s3-localhost-localstack-cloud